# Jasmine trigger Button Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have the following click handler wrapped in a class

```
var TestUI = function (chatClient, document, elements) {

TestUI.prototype = {

    applyListenersToElements: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.elements.myButton.click(function () {
            self.myClient.postData(data).then(function (response) {
                //all's good
                if(response)
                {
                    ....do something
                }
            }, function (err) {
                console.log("Error " + err);
            });
        });
    }       
}
```

How do I write a Jasmine test to simulate/perform the actual click event as if clicked on in a browser ? How do I mock the objects and events ?
Do I have to provide a HTML snippet in the mock or can I use the HTML that's in the actual file, perhaps using jasmine.getFixtures()

Answer (score 0):

Just come across this from a while ago seems answer my question.

https://luizfar.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/testing-events-on-jquery-objects-with-jasmine/

And I can read in HTML from an external file using  jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'my/new/path';

```
From https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery.
```

This is ok as well

```
http://codepen.io/jweden/pen/Irmil
```

Hope this helps anyone else